# global variables.Best way to approach this project

Tags: vb.net

I am building a game where a player moves between one of 13 regions - which i defined as a global variable "gsCurrentlyIn" - each round that passes some statistics for that region (eg "Region1") need to be updated - which i have also defined as global variables (eg "giRegion1Pop" for population, "giRegion1PlayerPercent" for popularity) etc.

Now the problem is how to pass the value of where the player currently is to update the appropriately named global variables for that region.

So we have:

```
gsCurrentlyIn = "Region1"
```

but we cant build the name of the correct global variable to call because it will be a string not the actual name of the variable.

```
"gi" + gsCurrentlyIn + "Pop" = 4 wont work.
```

is there a better way to go about this than the 100-odd global variable way I'm doing it?

I could have huge if/then or case statements for each variable - again that doesnt seem right.

Some people suggested reflection but I found it too confusing. If that is the only way maybe someone can dumb it down for me. But I find it hard to believe that this is that complicated.

Comment: I think the tag should be vb.net instead of vb? (since there is a reference to reflection)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array or a collection/dictionary instead of all different variables. The current region is than an number pointing to the proper index in the array

Comment: hmm - yeah maybe a public multidimensional array - Ill give it a shot and see. thx

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use a multi-dimensional array.  Build a *class* with an property for each of the attributes you track: Population, Popularity, etc.  Then use either a *collection* (ie: List(Of T) )or an array to hold an instance for your class for each region.